# Role level security with multiple users to filter on same IDs

Tags: security, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, roles, row-level-security

I have a PowerBI report that uses RLS to make sure the respective users only see their respective companies information (sales etc)
[image: This works]

The RLS is configured to the Users-table (DimUsers) as such: Email = Userprincipalname()
DimUsers is related to DimCompany with a one-to-one relationship, and then DimCompany filters FactSales and the rest of the data model.

This works fine. But i need to add more users to view the same company. Hence i will need more emails in DimUsers connected to the same DimUsers, and so it does not work with a one-to-one relationship anymore, and the RLS does not function. It needs to work for these setup:
[image: I need this to work]

How can i fix this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relationship should have "Cross filter direction" both and Apply security filter in both directions

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In general to make RLS simple, introduce a table with all the valid combinations, here (UserPrincipalName,CompanyId).  Then put the RLS predicate on that table and have it flow filters to the DimCompany table.